# amdgpu never sets the lowest P state

Tags: power-management, radeon, amd-graphics, amdgpu, 4k-monitor

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with 5.8 kernel and amdgpu driver for my RX 580.

```
# lspci | grep VGA
2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (rev e7)
```

However, there is a slight problem: P state is never set to lowest, thus I can hear slight coil whine while doing some casual browsing stuff :( Voltage and power consumption is also way too high for idle, 1.09V/42W is a no go by any means.

Everything is good on Windows though, proper 300Mhz mode (the lowest one) maintained while out of 3D apps. No coil whine (while not in game :) ) as well.

The display is running 4K@60Hz 200% scaling via DP on both systems.

Here is the sensors output for the GPU

```
amdgpu-pci-2d00
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:        1.09 V  
fan1:         758 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 3700 RPM)
edge:         +39.0°C  (crit = +94.0°C, hyst = -273.1°C)
power1:       42.02 W  (cap = 145.00 W)
```

I tried to play around with SCLK settings but no luck:

```
root@abyss:/sys/class/drm/card0/device# cat power_dpm_force_performance_level
auto
root@abyss:/sys/class/drm/card0/device# echo profile_min_sclk > power_dpm_force_performance_level 
root@abyss:/sys/class/drm/card0/device# sensors
iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +34.0°C  

nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +84.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +39.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

amdgpu-pci-2d00
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:        1.09 V  
fan1:         760 RPM  (min =    0 RPM, max = 3700 RPM)
edge:         +46.0°C  (crit = +94.0°C, hyst = -273.1°C)
power1:       75.14 W  (cap = 145.00 W)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:         +0.0°C  (high = +70.0°C)

root@abyss:/sys/class/drm/card0/device# cat power_dpm_force_performance_level
profile_min_sclk
root@abyss:/sys/class/drm/card0/device# cat pp_dpm_sclk
0: 300Mhz 
1: 600Mhz 
2: 900Mhz 
3: 1145Mhz 
4: 1215Mhz 
5: 1257Mhz 
6: 1300Mhz *
7: 1365Mhz
```

the same with manual:

```
root@abyss:/sys/class/drm/card0/device# echo manual > power_dpm_force_performance_level 
root@abyss:/sys/class/drm/card0/device# cat pp_dpm_sclk
0: 300Mhz 
1: 600Mhz 
2: 900Mhz 
3: 1145Mhz 
4: 1215Mhz 
5: 1257Mhz 
6: 1300Mhz *
7: 1365Mhz 
root@abyss:/sys/class/drm/card0/device# echo 0 > pp_dpm_sclk
root@abyss:/sys/class/drm/card0/device# cat pp_dpm_sclk
0: 300Mhz 
1: 600Mhz 
2: 900Mhz 
3: 1145Mhz 
4: 1215Mhz 
5: 1257Mhz 
6: 1300Mhz *
7: 1365Mhz
```

What else I can do to finally have it switching to 300Mhz with the lowest possible voltage? 1.09V is way too high for idle.

Answer (score 2):

I am having the same issue as you, but running an AMD RX570.

I never tried  changing any of these values via the terminal myself, I used CoreCTRL instead from ( https://gitlab.com/corectrl/corectrl ).
There I changed 'Performance Mode' to 'Advanced' and 'Power Profile' to 'Power Saving'. (Note it was set to power saving by default but it wasn't used properly it seems, so I had to switch back and forth to some other profiles first before it worked).
Now the card goes to the lowest p state when on the desktop and during simple browsing. Playing a game ramps it up to a high p state and gives me the fps I expect in gaming.